# C++ if statement with OR operator not working as I expect

Tags: c++, if-statement, string-comparison

I have been recently learning C++, and I have started a small project, so that I do not get bored after school.

I am creating a program that takes command arguments, and throws a "USAGE" message if it isn't formatted correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <-f/-c> <integer value>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( argv[1] == "-f" || argv[1] == "-F" )
        {

        }
        else if ( argv[1] == "-c" || argv[1] == "-C" )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <-f/-c> <integer value>" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but for some reason, whatever I type in throws a "USAGE" message.

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be fantastic!

Comment: how exactly are you typing what???? can you please add that info to the question???

Comment: I wonder why all the downvotes... It's a very basic question, but it is perfectly clear, and anybody who is not a C++ novice should be able to answer it immediately. Yet it's not something which is that easy to research (other than "learn the language", which is what OP is already doing), or even realize what is wrong, when you *are* a C++ novice.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. Thank you for explaining it. I thought `strcmp(1, 2)` was a `C` thing only

Comment: C++ has C strings still. But you're better of almost always using `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use `strcmp` to compare c-style strings from `string.h` library.

The function `strcmp(s1, s2)` returns `0` if the strings `s1` and `s2` are equal, `1` if `s1` and `s2` are not in alphabetical order and `-1` if `s1` and `s2` are in alphabetical order.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <-f/-c> <integer value>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-F") == 0 )
        {

        }
        else if ( strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-C") == 0 )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <-f/-c> <integer value>" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Commenting because this is accepted answer and has a few upvotes: While this is a possible solution, there's really no need to use `strcmp`, and it's not good C++. `std::string arg1(argv[1]);`, and then using normal C++ string handling would be *much* better.

Comment: @hyde You are absolutely right sir. Please also kindly suggest as to what should I do now?

Comment: You don't really have to do anything, as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43604180/1717300) already covers the `std::string` alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are compared with `strcmp`, not with `==`:

```
if ( !strcmp( argv[1], "-c" ) ) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way comparing `char*`s works. Either use `strcmp` or create a new `std::string` like so:

```
std::string argument(argv[1]);
if ( argument == "-f" || argument == "-F" )
{
    //some code here
}
else if ( argument == "-c" || argument == "-C" )
{
    //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to compare c-style strings with the `==` operator. This wont work as you expect in C++.

Instead you need to use the function `strcmp` or `equal` which compares two arbitrary sequences.

Also you could cast the c strings to `std::string` and then compare them.